# How do I Include plain text file org-mode as is for LaTeX export?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, pdf, text

I'm using #+INCLUDE: "./file.txt" to organize documents but including files this way is messing with linefeeds on org-mode export to LaTeX/Pdf. Is there a property or attribute that could tell org-mode to read from these included files as is. I've already converted the newlinews to unix standard, but since LaTeX interprets newlines as two lines separated by one blank line, the text is messy.

[image]

Comment: Can you give us an example of the text in `file.txt` and how it looks after export? Is this different than how text in your source .org file is exported?

Comment: A simple listing dir in Windows exported with pipes: ls > file.txt

Comment: Does the same text export how you want it if you insert it directly into the org file?

Comment: No, it's messy also. The linefeeds are ignored, but I think this is the behaviour of LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orgmode` exports to pdf using `LaTeX`. LaTeX ignores single line breaks normally, which can be confusing.

When you're importing a plain text file into org, you can wrap it in an `example` block to indicate that you want it exported 'as-is', without the normal LaTeX treatment of linebreaks:

```
#+include: file.txt example
```

For more details see [(org) Include Files](https://orgmode.org/manual/Include-Files.html) and [(org) Example blocks in LaTeX export](https://orgmode.org/manual/Example-blocks-in-LaTeX-export.html).